# How to convert .aaxc file to mp3 in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to change audiobook .aaxc to mp3 or any other audio format but conversion failed is showing.

`ffmpeg -i test.aaxc -c:a aac test.mp3`

I am beginner using ffmpeg on windows. there is so much errors so also guide to how to analyse there errors. one error is like **Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input** .

As llogan ask for i am sharing complete [log file](https://pastebin.com/VkEL60jd)

Comment: @llogan  I added the log file in above question.

Comment: Please note that the tag description for [tag:ffmpeg] states: "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on [su] or [video.se]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audible AAX files are encrypted M4B files, and they can be decrypted by specifying a 4-byte activation key.

```
ffmpeg -activation_bytes 1CEB00DA -i input.aax output.mp3
```

Comment: it's convert to .m4a but there is no audio while playing & how did you get activation key.

Comment: @leecarter See https://github.com/inAudible-NG/audible-activator

Comment: i run that script but because of different domain i can't login with selenium so you can tell other ways to know activation_byte

Comment: @leecarter That should be a new question because it's a different topic. Also, I don't have any other suggestions regarding activation bytes. I have no experience with Audible. This answer is only to directly answer the question "How to convert .aaxc file to mp3 in ffmpeg?"

Comment: While this works for aax, it does not work for aaxc files.

Answer (score 4):

Following information from [this](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/17559601585196510@sas2-2fa759678732.qloud-c.yandex.net/) patch to ffmpeg, you need a key/iv pair, which is unique for each book, to decrypt aaxc files. This key/iv, pair is provided by a special license request to the audible api.

The key/iv pair have to be decrypted from the license request response. Please take a look on [this](https://github.com/mkb79/Audible/issues/3#issuecomment-705262614) issue in my audible github package for more informations how to obtain the key/iv pair.